# Third party cookies deprecation for provider-hosted SP app

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, provider-hosted-app

We a provider-hosted app that performs client-side calls (by using ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory). It seems that such calls are not working when third-party cookies are disabled on a browser. Chrome and other browsers are blocking third party cookies by next year.
Of course users were able to un-block these cookies through the settings, but the sole fact that they had to do it caused some inconvenience specially for big organizations.

Is there any MS documentation regarding this or anyone has been able to figure out a way for moving forward?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft suggested changes to the `system.web` declaration in the `web.config` file. Setting the `SameSite` attribute to `None` and `requireSSL` to `true` might help, as it doesn’t force the requirement for the iFrame and host to be in the same domain.

See: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/net-update-on-azure-breaking-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app/ba-p/1132149

You can try removing the iFrame that is being injected by the SharePoint Add-in app. This could resolve the issue as the first-party site and the provider-hosted app would be the same.

See: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/net-update-on-azure-breaking-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app/ba-p/1132149